# How to cut the line before the specified character?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I would like to cut the line before the word "Number" in Bash. How can I do it?

One - Number Maps and Stuff
 Two - Number Other Things
 Three - Number Drinks
 Four - Number Foods

So, I would like to get output like this;

Maps and Stuff
Other Things
Drinks
Foods

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those lines are in a `file` and using `sed` the following command will do what you've asked.

```
sed -e 's/^.*- Number //g' file
```

That will output to stdout in that form.  To change the actual file use:

```
sed -i -e 's/^.*- Number //g' file
```

Or redirect the output to a new file:

```
sed -e 's/^.*- Number //g' file > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using plain 'ol `bash`:

```
$ while read -r line; do echo ${line#*Number}; done < file
Maps and Stuff
Other Things
Drinks
Foods
```